# Denormalizing an OrderedDict to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, hash-map

Cross post from [stackoverflow](//stackoverflow.com/questions/30354029/denormalization-python3-to-csv), as suggested.

I have an ordereddict, and I need to store it in CSV file.
Input:

```
dic = collections.OrderedDict([('k1', 'v1'),
                               ('k2', 'v2'),
                               ('k3', [ [('k3a',21), ('k3b',22)],
                                        [('k3a',23), ('k3b',24)] ]),
                               ('k4', [1,2,3,4])])

mapping = {'k3': ['k3a', 'k3b']}
```

Desired output:

```
k1,k2,k3a,k3b,k4
v1,v2,21,22,1
v1,v2,23,24,2
v1,v2,,,3
v1,v2,,,4
```

That is, substitute the top level keys in the **mapping** dictionary with the sub-keys in the OrderedDict, and add blank fields when no data is available.

My working code so far is:

```
import csv
import collections

max_len = 0
result = []
for k,v in dic.items():
    if isinstance(v, list) and len(v) > max_len:
        max_len = len(v)

for i in range(max_len):
    tmp = collections.OrderedDict()
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if not isinstance(v, list):
            tmp.update({k:v})
        else:
            if k in mapping and i < len(v):
                if isinstance(v[i], list):
                    for tup in v[i]:
                        tmp.update({tup[0]:tup[1]})
            elif k in mapping and i >= len(v):
                for mk in mapping[k]:
                    tmp.update({mk:''})
            else:
                try:
                    tmp.update({k:v[i]})
                except IndexError:
                    tmp.update({k:''})
    result.append(tmp)

with open("out.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, result[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Is there a cleaner/easier way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

- `tmp.update({k:v})` is an unusual way to perform `tmp[k] = v`
- Take advantage of the `max` builtin:

  ```
  max_len = max(len(v) for v in dic.values() if isinstance(v, list))
  ```
- To make the code easier to follow, you could first transform the dictionary to give it a consistent structure like this

  ```
  {'k1': ['v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v1'],
   'k2': ['v2', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2'],
   'k3a': [21, 23],
   'k3b': [22, 24],
   'k4': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
  ```

  using code like this

  ```
  mapped = collections.OrderedDict()
  for key, value in dic.items():
      if key in mapping:
          for sublist in value:
              for subkey, subvalue in sublist:
                  mapped.setdefault(subkey, []).append(subvalue)
      elif isinstance(value, list):
          mapped[key] = value
      else:
          mapped[key] = max_len * [value]
  ```
- Then you can take advantage of `itertools.zip_longest` to produce the output:

  ```
  with open("out.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
      writer.writerow(list(mapped.keys()))
      writer.writerows(itertools.zip_longest(*mapped.values(), fillvalue=''))
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the hints!
One question: does the dict transformation impact the performances, in case of a **big** dictionary and more complex values? (e.g., more than 50 keys and list of dictionaries as values)

Comment: @MarcoMilanesio It is best to time the code with real data if you are worried about performance. Note though that my version creates only one temporary dictionary while yours creates one for each row of output.